# How To add a Navbar section to an ASP MVC site?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to generate the following view:

```
 +----------------------------------+
 |/////|                            | 
 |/////|                            |
 |/////|                            |   
 |/////|                            |    
 |/////|       CONTENT              |      
 |/////|                            |     
 |/////|                            |     
 |/////|                            |  
 |/////|                            |
 |/////|                            |
 +-----+----------------------------+
    ^
    |
  space reserved 
  for navbar
```

I have been using DevExpress' Splitter for this in the past:

```
settings.Name = "ContentSplitter";
    settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
    settings.Height = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
    settings.Styles.Pane.Paddings.Padding = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(0);
    settings.Styles.Pane.Border.BorderWidth = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(0);

    settings.Panes.Add(subpane => {
        subpane.Name = "ContentLeft";
        subpane.PaneStyle.CssClass = "leftPane";
        subpane.ShowCollapseBackwardButton = DefaultBoolean.False;
        subpane.Size = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(250);
        subpane.PaneStyle.Paddings.Padding = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(1);
        subpane.SetContent(() => {
            Html.RenderPartial("ContentLeftPartialView");
        });
    });

    settings.Panes.Add(subpane => {
        subpane.Name = "ContentCenter";
        subpane.PaneStyle.CssClass = "contentPane";
        subpane.ScrollBars = System.Web.UI.WebControls.ScrollBars.Auto;
        subpane.Separator.Visible = DefaultBoolean.True;
        subpane.Separator.SeparatorStyle.Border.BorderWidth = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(1);
        subpane.Separator.SeparatorStyle.BorderTop.BorderWidth = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(0);
        subpane.SetContent(RenderBody().ToHtmlString());
    });

}).GetHtml()
```

But I am trying to generate this navbar as a partial view, meaning it can be made/kept on every page.

However, I can't seem to find a way of having the content fill only the rest of the view/page?

How should I be defining this layout (using `mainLayout/ViewStart` etc) so that it reserves that part of the screen?

Since I wish to move away from DevExpress, how can i achieve this 'reserved' part of the screen?

Cheers for the help (and listening to the blabbering of me trying to explain)

/******************************************************************************************************/

To explain/clarify further, I am trying to Start with a 'new', 'blank' project with a designated navbar space to the left hand side (the default MVC project does not do this by default) and so I was trying to generate this manually (using partial views, etc). I **do not** want to use third party plugins (i.e. dev express above).

So how can I 'reserve' the navbar space on screen/split the screen into sections like above?

Comment: take a look into partialView,   the navigation is a sperate cshtml file,  the template holds the placeholder of partialView or renderView.   these can also be sent a model if needed

Comment: I'm having the trouble of ruling out devExpress, actually so that I can generate a vertical navbar - not the navigation itself @davethecoder

Comment: yeah but same, renderParial, renderAction  they all fill designated space?   If you want code, then use the renderAction, this will return its own view etc.  its either that, or your going to have to try and reword your issue, as this does not make much sense with regards to what you want to do, and why the result is an error.

Comment: edited question for clarification

Comment: I think I get you,  in views / shared you create a layout page ( this is like a master layout )   in there do html two column design, in first column, create a renderPartial, in second column add a @renderBody(), the other option is to buy / aquire a template / theme